# Git: Ignoring files in a currently-tracked directory

Tags: git

I've got a bare repo which is used as an origin for two computers.

I have a currently-tracked /furniture/ directory in git which I want to untrack and .gitignore on both computers.

All repos are synced to begin with.

On Computer 1

```
$ git rm -r --cached furniture
```

successfully removes the files from the local repo, but leaves them in my working tree. All good so far.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

deleted:    furniture/file1.png
deleted:    furniture/file2.png
```

I commit this update and push to the remote, and pull from Computer 2.

But now the files in the working tree on Computer 2 vanish.

Option 1: Recreate the folder on Computer 2 by scp, then promptly .gitignore it there.

Option 2: Use git update-index --assume unchanged on every computer

Option 3: ??? A better way ???

It seems like there ought to be an easy way for me to just tell all of the repos to stop tracking the files any more, as if they've been in the .gitignore file all along.

All my googling has given me is that rm --cached is the solution to this; but it doesn't seem to stop the delete command being sent to the other repos' working trees, even though it works fine on Computer 1.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following command

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

To make git track changes again, do

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

Documentation [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html)

Comment: But that will only tell Computer 1 to ignore the file, right? Added this into the question as another option...

Comment: Don't do that. The flag means something else. This usage is a bad side effect, and some commands will detect the changes and add the files, probably when you least expect it. I do have a patch in process to update the documentation to be clearer about the flags purpose (and that it's not a poor man's ignore flag!).